# JS objects for Timer on Webpage

Tags: javascript, timer

What are the objects in JavaScript that we use for running time on webpage?

I tried using `getElementId()` method and could not do it.

Comment: So you want to get the local time and place that on the webpage somewhere, like a timer?

Comment: Please consider rephrasing the question in order others could undertand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current date and time,

```
var now = new Date()
var deadline = new Date(now.getFullYear, now.getMonth, now.getDate, now.getHours, now.getMinutes + 15);
```

Then you can fill an element with the deadline variable.

See here
https://blog.smalldo.gs/2013/12/create-simple-countdown/